# Getting all instances of child node using xml.etree.ElementTree

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, elementtree

I have the following XML file as input:

```
<Test>
  <callEvents>
    <moc>
      <causeForTermination>0</causeForTermination>
      <serviceCode>
        <teleServiceCode>11</teleServiceCode>
      </serviceCode>
      <dialledDigits>5555555</dialledDigits>
      <connectedNumber>77777</connectedNumber>
    </moc>

    <moc>
      <causeForTermination>0</causeForTermination>
      <serviceCode>
        <teleServiceCode>11</teleServiceCode>
      </serviceCode>
      <dialledDigits>2222222</dialledDigits>
    </moc>
  </callEvents>
  <callEventsCount>100</callEventsCount>
</Test>
```

I want to output all the values for dialledDigits. However, my code only displays the first instance of dialledDigits.

```
dialledDigits {} 5555555
```

My desired output should contain both instances.

```
dialledDigits {} 5555555
dialledDigits {} 2222222
```

Here is my code

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('as.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
callevent=root.find('callEvents')

Moc1=callevent.find('moc')

for node in Moc1.getiterator():
    if node.tag=='dialledDigits':
        print node.tag, node.attrib, node.text
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [`findall`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html?highlight=findall#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.findall):

```
moc1 = callevent.findall('moc')

for moc in moc1:
    for node in moc.getiterator():
        if node.tag=='dialledDigits':
            print node.tag, node.attrib, node.text
```

Output:

```
dialledDigits {} 5555555
dialledDigits {} 2222222
```

Comment: But shouldn't there be a way to do it without an explicit if check, but rather like "for node in moc.inter("dialledDigits")"?

Answer (score 15):

You can also write an **XPath expression**. Just 2 lines instead of 5 and a single loop:

```
for node in tree.findall('.//callEvents/moc/dialledDigits'):
    print node.tag, node.attrib, node.text
```

Demo:

```
>>> import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
>>> 
>>> 
>>> tree = ET.parse('as.xml')
>>> root = tree.getroot()
>>> 
>>> for node in tree.findall('.//callEvents/moc/dialledDigits'):
...     print node.tag, node.attrib, node.text
... 
dialledDigits {} 5555555
dialledDigits {} 2222222
```

Comment: yes, xpath will work, Thank you. The  `xpath` method is not available for ET.  It is present in the `lxml`. +upvote

Comment: xpath syntax is available in ET: that's what alecxe used in the `findall` call....

Comment: I've only dabbled a bit and never used `root = tree.getroot()` yet. It is used in your code but, I can't see why?

Answer (score 1):

`find()` will return first tag object, so use `finadall()` which return all tag objects`

```
>>> Moc1=callevent.find('moc')
>>> Moc1
<Element 'moc' at 0x869a2ac>
>>> Moc1=callevent.findall('moc')
>>> Moc1
[<Element 'moc' at 0x869a2ac>, <Element 'moc' at 0x869a4ec>]
>>>
```

Iterate on it:

```
>>> Mocs=callevent.findall('moc')
>>> for moc in Mocs:
...     for node in moc.getiterator():
...         if node.tag=='dialledDigits':
...             print node.tag, node.attrib, node.text
... 
dialledDigits {} 5555555
dialledDigits {} 2222222
```